# Analyzing User Agent strings

Tags: user-agent

I've recently inherited a large codebase for an online product. One of the things I'm trying to determine is what are the most predominant clients people are using to access the product online (*e.g. Browsers, Mobile Devices, IPads, etc...*). On the up side I have a database table with all the User Agent strings (*about 10 million records*). Can anyone recommend a tool that can analyze and summarize the User Agent data?

***Note**: Keep in mind, these are not IIS Logs. This is a table of just User Agents strings that were captured using a variety of other processes.*

Answer (score 0):

Never heard about such kind of software. I may suggest the following option.
You can export this table (with user agent log) to some text file which can reproduce IIS or Apache log structure (simulate) and then feed this log file to standard web log analyzing tool.